# How to add integers to an array and get a random number?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, random, int

It's a favorite panel.
You can select numbers (with button click) and than I would like to add this number to an array and than get a random number from this array.

```
public int runs;
public int randomNumber;
public int[] favorites = new int[75];

public void RandomButton()
{
    if (DataController.Instance.group == 3)
    {
            favorites[randomNumber] = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, favorites.Length);
            Debug.Log(favorites[randomNumber]);
    }
}

public void b0()
{
    for (runs = 0; runs < favorites.Length; runs++)
    {
        favorites[runs] = 0;
    }
}

public void b1()
{
    for (runs = 0; runs < favorites.Length; runs++)
    {
        favorites[runs] = 1;
    }
}
```

I'm stuck , because I get random number between 0 - 75. I would like to have a random number from the "favorites" array after I click on the buttons.

Comment: Use a `List<int>` instead of a fixed size array, it's better suited for your needs.

Comment: @Gusman in Unity a public array is initialized via the Inspector and is adjustable by the Developer. So unless you need to add or remove elements on runtime via code a `List<int>` or `int[]` behave basically the same way ;)

Comment: @derHugo if you read the question you will see the user is adding dynamically values at runtime via user interaction. And having the `Count` property to know how many numbers are in the list is the key to solve his problem. So, `List<int>` is what he needs.

Comment: @Gusman good point! Actually didn't note that the adding of values was also part of the question

Comment: @derHugo The problem is the code has nothing to do with the question, it's totally different what he's asking to what he's doing ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing here

```
favorites[randomNumber] = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, favorites.Length);
```

Is assign a random value between `0` and `74` to an item in your array .. depending on whatever value `randomNumber` has at that moment ...

What you rather want to do is actually access the value from the array using the random value as index like

```
randomNumber = favorites [UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, favorites.Length)];
Debug.Log(randomNumber);
```

---

However what difference will it make if you are filling your array with always the same numbers using `b0` and `b1`?

After running these methods all elements are either `0` or `1` anyway ...

---

Anyway in your question you are also asking for how to **Add** a number.

You shouldn't use an array for this but rather a `List<int>` like

```
public List<int> favorites = new List<int>();

public void AddNumber(int newNumber)
{
    favorites.Add(newNumber);
}

public void RandomButton()
{
    if (DataController.Instance.group == 3)
    {
            randomNumber = favorites[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, favorites.Count)];
            Debug.Log(randomNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think he wants `var number = favorites[rnd.Next(0, favorites.Length)];`...

Comment: That's basically what [`Random.Range(0, favorites.Count)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html) (or Length for array) does ...

Comment: `Next` upper limit is [exclusive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netcore-3.1#System_Random_Next_System_Int32_System_Int32_), not inclusive.

Comment: Same for [`Random.Range`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html) when used with `int` arguments: `Return a random integer number between min [inclusive] and max [exclusive] (Read Only).`

Comment: Thanks! Your comment is very helpful but I would like to generate a random number from this array. b0 - add number 0 to position 0 and b1 add number 1 to position 1 so favorites[0,1] and etc.. and from this favorites[] generate a random number 0 or 1 or etc

Comment: @Xerodus well currently you are setting **all** elements to `0` in `b0` and **all** elements to `1` in `b1` ... what sense would it make to iterate through the array if anyway only setting one specific entry to a specific value?

Comment: I'am a beginner :D should I use instead of `public void b0()
{
    for (runs = 0; runs < favorites.Length; runs++)
    {
        favorites[runs] = 0;
    }
}         `  simple             favorites[0] = 0;

Comment: @Xerodus well depends what you want to do there but yes this would basically behave equally ... still unsure though what you are trying to achieve here

Answer (score -1):

```
if (DataController.Instance.group == 3)
{
        var randomIndex = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, favorites.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(favorites[randomIndex]); // random item from your array
}
```

[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297853/how-to-get-random-values-from-array-in-c-sharp)