# C# Select random element from List

Tags: c#, random

I am creating a little quiz console application.
I have made a list with 3 questions in it.
How can I let the program randomly select a question and print it out int the console?

I have tried some different codes but can't seem the get it working for some reason.
This is the last code I tried, which I got from another user from this site, but I get the errors:

> The name 'string' does not exist in the current context.

"Since `Quiz.Questions.main()` returns **void**, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression".

Here is the last piece of code which I tried:

```
class Questions
{
    public static void main()
    {
        var questions = new List<string>{
            "question1",
            "question2",
            "question3"};
        int index = Random.Next(strings.Count);
        questions.RemoveAt(index);
        return questions;

    }
```

}

Thank you all for your responses. 
I have fixed my problem by creating an array instead of an List.
This is my code now :

```
class Questions
{
    public static void main()
    {
        string[] questions = new string[3];
        questions[0] = "question1";
        questions[1] = "question2";
        questions[2] = "question3";
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Console.WriteLine(questions[rnd.Next(0,2)]);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you call your method? As its currently a void-type you have to leave out the return-value `questions`

Comment: duplicate => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019417/access-random-item-in-list

Comment: var randomQuestion = questions[new Random().Next(questions.Count)];    Be sure first that the list is not null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access random item in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019417/access-random-item-in-list)

Answer (score 26):

Are you sure that you want to remove a question and return the rest of the questions?
Should you not only select one? Somthing like this :

```
public static void main()
{
    var random = new Random();
    var questions = new List<string>{
        "question1",
        "question2",
        "question3"};
    int index = random.Next(questions.Count);
    Console.WriteLine(questions[index]);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need a System.Console.WriteLine statment.

```
class Questions
{
    public static void main()
    {
        var questions = new List<string>{
            "question1",
            "question2",
            "question3"};
        int index = Random.Next(questions.Count);
        System.Console.WriteLine(questions[index]);

    }
}
```

Comment: Also strings.Count should be replaced by questions.Count and Random.Next(...) by new Random().Next(...).

Comment: Thanks Alexey.  Corrected.

Comment: @AlexeyMitev: `new Random().Next` has the pitfall that it will not create different numbers if it's called repeatedly at short intervals.

Answer (score 6):

For other searchers benefit: If you want a depleting list so you ensure you use all items in a random fashion then do this:

```
//use the current time to seed random so it's different every time we run it
Random rand = new Random(DateTime.Now.ToString().GetHashCode());
var list = new List<string>{ "item1", "item2", "item3"};

//keep extracting from the list until it's depleted
while (list.Count > 0) {
    int index = rand.Next(0, list.Count);
    Console.WriteLine("Rand Item: " + list[index]);
    list.RemoveAt(index);
}
```

Comment: Note: the call to [`rand.Next`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=net-5.0#System_Random_Next_System_Int32_System_Int32_) *should* have `list.Count` as the second argument rather than `list.Count - 1` as suggested in [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28214949) as the second argument to `Random.Next(int, int)` is exclusive. The suggested edit should be rejected.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this

```
public static void main()
{
    var questions = new List<string>{
        "question1",
        "question2",
        "question3"};
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int index = rnd.Next(questions.Count)
    string question  = questions[index];
    questions.RemoveAt(index); // Are you sure you neex to remove?

    System.Console.WriteLine(question);
}
```

There is a typo in where you are using `string` instead of `questions`.  Also, `Random` object needs to be initalised.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this could be what you want:

```
private Random rng;
T PickRandom<T>(List<T> list)
{
    return list[rng.NextInt(list.Count)];
}
```

You can call it on your list to get a random element from it.

Comment: I think that Random.NextInt() do not exists in c# (it does on Java). If I am correct, the code should be rng.Next(list.Count) instead of rng.NextInt(list.Count).

Answer (score 1):

> "The name 'string' does not exists in current context"

I assume you want

```
int index = random.Next(questions.Count); // according to the lower-case random see last paragraph
```

instead of

```
int index = Random.Next(strings.Count);
```

Since there is no variable with the name `strings` and you want to remove one question anyway.

Also, you cannot return something from a `void` method. So create one that returns the list:

```
private Random random = new Random();
List<string> GetRemoveQuestion(List<string> questions)
{
        int index = random.Next(questions.Count);
        questions.RemoveAt(index);
        return questions;
}
```

**Edit**: last but not least, you cannot use `Random.Next`. That would presume that there is a `static` `Next` method in `Random` which is not the case. Therefore i have shown above how you create and use an instance. Note that you should not create it i the method itself since it is seeded with the curent time. If you'd call this method very fast you'd get the same "random" value often.

Have a look at [msdn at the remarks section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.random.aspx) for more details.

Comment: pretty sure Random does not have a static Next method

Comment: @WeylandYutani: Thanks, edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of minor errors.

You need a reference to a `Rand` object. You are looking at `strings` instead of `questions`. You are removing an element instead of selecting it.

Try this:

```
void Main()
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    var questions = new List<string>{
        "question1",
        "question2",
        "question3"};
    int index = rand.Next(questions.Count);
    return questions[index];
    // If you want to use Linq then
    // return questions.Skip(index).Take(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### >= .NET 8

With .NET 8 (which is currently still in preview) we get the [`GetItems<T>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.getitems?view=net-8.0) method that lets you choose a specified number of items from an `Array<T>` or `Span<T>` i. e. it would also allow you to easily select 2 or more questions. The method returns an array (also there are other overrides) of the choices made.

```cs
var questions = new List<string>
{
    "question1",
    "question2",
    "question3"
};
var numberOfQuestionsToSelectRandomly = 1;
var randomQuestion = Random.Shared.GetItems<string>(CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan(questions), numberOfQuestionsToSelectRandomly);
Console.WriteLine(randomQuestion[0]);
```

> I am using [`CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.collectionsmarshal.asspan?view=net-8.0#system-runtime-interopservices-collectionsmarshal-asspan-1(system-collections-generic-list((-0)))) to create a `Span<T>` from the `List<T>`. Using this method you should not add/ remove any items from the list. Alternatively you can turn the list into an array and pass that array to `GetItems<T>()`.

There is [`Random.GetItems<T>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.getitems?view=net-8.0) as well as [`RandomNumberGenerator.GetItems<T>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator.getitems?view=net-8.0) which uses a cryptographically secure number generator to choose the items.