# Open random website from list of sites each time button clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, button

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start("http://google.com");
    }
```

for example, then when clicked again it has a chance of opening like yahoo or even google again.
tried

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start("http://google.com");
        Process.Start("http://yahoo.com");
        Process.Start("http://stackoverflow.com");
    }
```

but that opens up all 3 sites at the same time in my default browser
I want it to open 1 out of those 3 sites randomly each time the button is clicked.

Comment: You can use the `Random` class to choose a random number and a `switch` or some `if` statements. Do some googling.

Comment: First of all, can you use IP addresses?  How else will you get random websites?

Comment: dustin i dont want it to be random random, im gonna add the options of websites myself that i want to be randomly chosen to be opened when button is clicked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Select random element from List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19318430/c-sharp-select-random-element-from-list)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Random` class and limit the random numbers within an interval:

Java sample as original post was not marked with language, for C# - remove `final` and use `System.Random` to select value:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    final String[] urls = {
      "http://google.com",
      "http://yahoo.com",
      "http://stackoverflow.com"
    };

    final int pick = (int)(Math.random() * urls.length);
    Process.Start(urls[pick]);
}
```

Comment: It had no language tag, I added C# based on the code. I don't think OP's code is valid Java?

Comment: `Process` makes use of `IDisposable` which it inherits from `Component`.  Just something to keep in mind... as you want to properly dispose of it.

Comment: yeah sorry im new to the site forgot to add what language but yes it is c#

Answer (score 2):

You can create a string array to hold the site addresses, like so:

```
string[] sites = {
    "http://google.com",
    "http://yahoo.com",
    "http://stackoverflow.com" };
```

And then use the `Random` class to select one of those sites on your button click:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    Process.Start(sites[random.Next(sites.Length)]);
}
```

The `Next` method of the random class will return a value less than the specified number, so no chance of an array out of bounds exception

Comment: It would be better to show correct usage of `Random`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number (or at least add comment).

Comment: You'd have to click pretty quickly for this code to fail in that way @AlexeiLevenkov

Answer (score 0):

Random number generator (should be a library for it in c#.

Add in a couple variables with your links, maybe store them in an array.

Then run that line you have with the array at the index that was randomly generated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int website = rnd.Next(0, numOfWebsites);
switch(website)
{
    case 0:
    {
        Process.Start("http://google.com");
        break;
    }
    case 1:
    {
        Process.Start("http://yahoo.com");
        break;
    }
}
```

You can use a switch case statement for readability with a random number generator. I apologize if i made any errors as i don't use C# much. A if else statement would also work for a situation like this.

Comment: might have been a copy and paste from another project lol. i'll fix that.

Comment: It should also be `rnd.Next(0, numOfWebsites)`, or you'll never hit google (and start with `case 0`). And `Process.Start` with a capital `S`.

Comment: 'control cannot fall out of switch from final case label' shows that error for string 0 and 1