# How to call List of methods randomly

Tags: c#, .net

I have few methods say

- Method1()
- Method2()

  ...
- Method5()

Now when I execute my form I want to call these methods randomly and print their output.

How can I do this?

Comment: share some code, what have you tried so far, what kind of methods do you want to call, do you expect a return value etc...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate random int number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706500/how-to-generate-random-int-number)

Comment: Have you tried generating a  random number and using a switch case based on that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access random item in list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019417/access-random-item-in-list)

Comment: Why -1 for question? this question is totally different from question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706500/how-to-generate-random-int-number.

Comment: Also I am not managing any list I just have 5 methods which will print some value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try some thing like this:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
// I suppose that you have 5 methods. If you have a greater number of methods
// just change the 6.
var number = rnd.Next(1,6);
switch(number)
{
    case 1:
       // call Method1
    case 2:
      // call Method2 
}
```

Comment: Oops you area correct. Thank you very much for your comment !

Comment: This will need a check in if this is in a loop and if you only want to call each one once if you call each as many times then this is fine.

Answer (score 6):

Create a list of methods, and pick one. Call that one:

```
List<Action> list = new List<Action>();
list.Add(this.Method1);

// Get random number
Random rnd = new Random();
int i = rnd.Next(0, list.Count);

// Call
list[i]();
```

Note that this only works if the signature is the same (in this case having no parameters). Else you could do the adding like this:

```
list.Add(() => this.Method1(1));
list.Add(() => this.Method2(1, 2));
```

If the method return a value, you should use `Func<T>` instead of `Action`, where `T` is the output type.

Comment: @sandy: Need more help?