# c# First in Any out collections? Can't find and Don't know where to look

Tags: c#, collections

I know exactly what I am looking for, but not how to ask for it in a search engine. I want a collection that can hold any number of objects including duplicates and allows for them to be pulled out randomly. Similar to a deck of cards.

I don't know what this kind of collection would be called in c#. I imagined FIAO(First In Any Out) but that pulls up nothing. Some direction would be appreciated.

Comment: `List<T>` is good enough. Also I'm  not sure what does "First In Any Out"  even mean.

Comment: @LuisLavieri There is no `ArrayList<T>` in c#. Are you confusing with java?

Comment: What structures have you tried, and what problems have you had using them?

Comment: Yes. My bad. List<T>

Comment: In java you can use a set, which has the function .removeAny(). A set in java though cannot contain duplicates. In my case I want to have what is essentially a shuffled deck. I put a bunch of stuff in, but then when I pull from it I get random objects out which are then removed from the container.

Comment: In other words I very decidedly do not want to preserve the order of the objects I put in.

Comment: If you are using this for a deck of cards, is there a reason you want duplicates?

Comment: Imagine its magic cards. This kind of deck could contain duplicates of the same card.

Comment: @AndrewAdkins A deck of cards is conceptually ordered (there is such a thing as a "top card").  Of course, if your actual situation is different, and doesn't need a logical ordering, that's fine, but if you're actually modeling a deck (and aren't using it for a game that uses the top or bottom of the deck), you may want to consider an ordered collection.

Comment: For the sake of simplicity I want to know if there is a collection that does this.

Comment: Also the deck is just an example to show what I am going for. The reality is I don't want to pull things in order because I do not need to and do not want to.

Comment: I was hoping that I could avoid prediction through not keeping the actual 'deck' in memory. I found a fairly simple random function using Lists somewhere else. I was hoping there was a collection built out of the box for this task, but there does not seem to be one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019417/access-random-item-in-list

Comment: `IEnumerable` would be a nice collection.  The collection would in theory work like a *First In, First Out*.  Because every time you add an item, it will take the next index.  So when you loop, it will iterate from the first index onward.

Comment: Well nevermind about my previous comment. I would like to remove by index but list does not seem to work that way. It seems to work by value. I wish I knew my way around C# a bit better.

Comment: A data structure with no order and allowing duplicates is called a bag or multiset. There is a "Bag" implementation in the PowerCollections library.

Comment: Cool, now I know what to call it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [ConcurrentBag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx) - I'm not sure if there's a non-concurrent version of this data structure though.

Comment: This is currently the closest thing to what I am looking for.

Comment: What would be the difference between a concurrent and non concurrent version?

Comment: ConcurrentBag<T> is thread-safe, meant for programs where it is accessed by producers and consumers. This means that (sometimes, when there is real contention between threads) there is a higher cost adding and removing items - but for the most part, this will be negligible.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be what I want.

Answer (score 0):

A Dictionary does not guarantee any particular order of retrieval, with the Keys collection not being ordered.  You could keep an incrementing count in the value to signify duplicates.