# How to get a random item from a List

Tags: c#, list

Good day
I have this array and list and i would like to get a random value from the list

```
random Ram = new Random();
String[] Test= {"C2", "C3", "C4"};

List<String> LTest = new List<String>(Test);

String var = Ram.Next(LTest);
```

> Error -cannot convert from system.collection.generic.list to 'Int'

and also i would like to continue to remove the object from the list and add it to a new one

```
Test.remove(Var);

newlist.add(Var);
```

thank you.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to choose an item from the list at random, you can do it a couple ways.

You can use random to compute an integer, and use that as an index:

```
var index = random.Next(list.Count);
var randomItem = list[index];
```

Or you can just sort the list randomly and take the first one:

```
var item = list.OrderBy( s => random.NextDouble() ).First();
```

The first method is very common; the second method is handy if you expect to be picking more than one random item from the list and you wish to avoid repetition. Just take the first, second, third, etc. items.

Comment: I think the second method is better in the case of non-indexed collections (like `IEnumerable`) because it means you don't need to access `list` twice, thereby more DRY. But for indexed collections (like `IList`), the first method should be used, otherwise it will be really slow.

Answer (score 3):

**[`Random.Next`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)** accepts a parameter of **`int`**.Also **`don't`** use **`var`** since its a **[`reserved keyword`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/)** in **`c#`**, You need

```
String nextVal = Ram.Next(LTest.Count);
```

Comment: Props for teaching me what [Contextual Keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/) are in C#; I didn't realize `var` wasn't a reserved word!

Comment: @Poosh Thanks for the headsup

Comment: I wasn't being sarcastic. I think you actually can use `var` as a variable name in that context (based on what the link says; I haven't tried it). But it may depend on the version of C#...

Comment: yes you can , but better not