# generic dictionary param c# (return random key from it)

Tags: c#, dictionary, generics

Is it possible to have a function that receives a generic dictionary param and return a random key from it? Since dictionary "key" values can be any data type, I would like the dictionary param to be generic and return a random key from it no matter what data type. I wrote this so far but am getting an error.

```
Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
dict.Add(1, "1003206");
dict.Add(2, "1234567");
dict.Add(3, "5432567");

int randomKey = (int)RandomDictionaryKeyValue<Dictionary<int, string>>(dict);

private T RandomDictionaryKeyValue<T>(Dictionary<T, T> dict)
    {
    List<T> keyList = new List<T>(dict.Keys);

    Random rand = new Random();
    return keyList[rand.Next(keyList.Count)];
}
```

I'm getting error:

> CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from `'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, string>'` to `'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, string>, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, string>>'`

I know how to get [Access random item in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019417/access-random-item-in-list), but I don't know how to correctly pass dictionary to my method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have specified the same generic type for both the key and value of your dictionary.

```
private TKey RandomDictionaryKeyValue<TKey, TValue>(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict)
{
    //snip
}
```

Comment: Obviously you can't create `Random` as shown in this post, but everyone knows that - so just be aware that the sample shows how to pass dictionary as parameter *and not* how to get random element from a list - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number

Comment: Good spot @AlexeiLevenkov, I've removed the content entirely.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get a random key from your dictionary, you just have to pass the key type and the valu type to your method, not the whole dictionary type:

```
private TKey RandomDictionaryKeyValue<TKey, TValue>(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict)
{
    List<TKey> keyList = new List<TKey>(dict.Keys);

    Random rand = new Random();
    return keyList[rand.Next(keyList.Count)];
}
```

And use it like:

```
Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
dict.Add(1, "1003206");
dict.Add(2, "1234567");
dict.Add(3, "5432567");

int randomKey = RandomDictionaryKeyValue<int, string>(dict);
```

Comment: Or even the example usage, that won't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
dict.Add(1, "1003206");
dict.Add(2, "1234567");
dict.Add(3, "5432567");

int randomKey = (int)RandomDictionaryKeyValue<int, string>(dict);
```

Figured out the answer before I came back here to check.

```
private object RandomDictionaryKeyValue<T1, T2>(object dict)
{
    var dict2 = (Dictionary<T1, T2>)dict;
    List<T1> keyList = new List<T1>(dict2.Keys);                                                                                                                        

    Random rand = new Random();
    return keyList[rand.Next(keyList.Count)];
}
```