# Display/Print the Contents of a List Randomize with and without LINQ

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to display the contents of a list randomized with and without LINQ.

Normal List Output Example:
Prada, Adidas, Levis, Polo, Guess

Randomized List Output Example:
Polo, Adidas, Prada, Guess, Levis

```
        List<string> clothingBrands = new List<string>()
        { "Prada","Adidas","Levis", "Polo","Gucci",
          "Calvin Klein","Aeropostale","Tommy Hilfiger","Puma","American Eagle",
          "Lacoste","Hollister","Guess","Under Armour","Old Navy",
          "Banana Republic","Hugo Boss", "Diesel","Coach","AND1"};


   private static void RandomzeClothingBrands(List<string> clothingBrands)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();

        int i = 1;
        foreach (string item in clothingBrands)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{i}.{item}");
        }
    }
```

How can I accomplish printing out the contents of the list randomized every time?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @royalTS I edited my initial post.

Comment: For a non-LINQ solution, you might want to look for "shuffle" algorithms, like Fisher-Yates as displayed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1262619/1336590

Comment: So many duplicate it's hard to choose one!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access random item in list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019417/how-to-access-random-item-in-list)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Randomize a List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To randomise a list in a very trivial way, you could just use random and `OrderBy`

***Note*** : there **are** more reliable ways to randomise a list

```
private static Random _rand = new Random();

...

foreach (string item in clothingBrands.OrderBy(x => _rand.Next()))
{
     Console.WriteLine($"{i}.{item}");
}
```

Comment: But you hold an hammer!

Comment: @xdtTransform do you mean dup hammer? oh i can swing if you make me multiples of 5 again

Comment: Looking at your top 20 recent answer, I have pin some of them to read them latter. I mean they are great, and Worth every upvote they have. I was just surprise by this.